# How to create listBuffer in collect function

Tags: scala, collect, listbuffer

I tought that List is enough but I need to add element to my list.

I've tried to put this in ListBuffer constructor but without result.

```
  var leavesValues: ListBuffer[Double] =
    leaves
      .collect { case leaf: Leaf => leaf.value.toDouble }
      .toList
```

Later on I'm going to add value to my list so my expected output is mutable list.

[Solution of Raman Mishra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54035194/7990631)

But what if I need to append single value to the end of leavesValues

1. I can reverse but it's not good enough
2. I can use ListBuffer like below but I believe that there is cleaner solution:

   ```
   val leavesValues: ListBuffer[Double] = ListBuffer()
   leavesValues.appendAll(leaves
     .collect { case leaf: Leaf => leaf.value.toDouble }
     .toList)
   ```

Comment: you can do it without using Listbuffer value :: leavesValues.

Comment: Please ask separate question if you have more than one question.

Comment: example how to do this without listBuffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  case class Leaf(value:String)

  val leaves = List(Leaf("5"), Leaf("6"), Leaf("7"), Leaf("8") ,Leaf("9") )

  val leavesValues: List[Double] =
    leaves
      .collect { case leaf: Leaf => leaf.value.toDouble }

  val value = Leaf("10").value.toDouble

  val answer = value :: leavesValues

  println(answer)
```

you can do it like this after getting the list of leavesValues you can prepand the value you want to add into the list.

Comment: What if I need to put value behind _leavesValues_
like `val answer = leavesValues :: value`
Let's say that _value_ is single element

Comment: @MrNetroful then  you have two options you either you can revers the list and then prepand or you can use listBuffer and do leavesValue += value

Comment: Is there any way to create _ListBuffer_ in constructor passing list or by collect?

Comment: What exactly you want to do please put a well defined question then only we can help you.

Comment: Edited answer above