# ListBuffer from collect func

Tags: scala, collect

Hi I'm wordering how could I simplify code below:

```
val leavesValues: ListBuffer[Double] = ListBuffer()
leavesValues.appendAll(
  leaves
    .collect { case leaf: Leaf => leaf.value.toDouble }
    .toList
)
leavesValues
```

I hope there is possibility to make this as oneliner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you want it a `ListBuffer` to begin with??? Mutable containers should be avoided, and in scala you almost never need them, except for some rare corner cases. I suggest, that you just pretend they don't exist at all until you get enough grasp of the language to be able to confidently distinguish those rare scenarios.

Having said that, conversion between collection types can be done without intermediaries using a thing called `breakOut`. This is how you use it:

```
import scala.collection.breakOut 
val leavesValues: ListBuffer[Double] = leaves.collect { 
  case leaf: Leaf => leaf.value.toDouble
}(breakOut)
```

Comment: I need to append element to the end of list and so I cannot `list::value`.
More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54034675/how-to-create-listbuffer-in-collect-function/54035194?noredirect=1#comment94908808_54035194)

Comment: This answer is better than mine, I'd suggest to accept it. I personally did not know about `breakout` till now. However, I'd also suggest to edit the answer. First, let him have his `ListBuffer` and than explain, why that might not be the best collection to work with. Also `???` can be replaced with `?`.

Comment: @MrNetroful don't append elements to existing lists. That's a bad idea too.

Answer (score 2):

Is following simple enough ?

```
val leavesValues: ListBuffer[Double] = ListBuffer(leaves.collect { case leaf: Leaf => leaf.value.toDouble } :_*)
```

If `Leaf` is a case class:

```
val leavesValues: ListBuffer[Double] = ListBuffer(leaves.collect { case Leaf(value) => value.toDouble } :_*)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `to` generic conversion method (in Scala <2.13):

```
val leavesValues = leaves.collect {
  case leaf: Leaf => leaf.value.toDouble
}.to[ListBuffer]
```

Using `to` is similar to `breakOut`, in the sense that it uses the `CanBuildFrom` machinery to do the conversion, except here you can provide just the target collection type (without element type) directly to the method. Sadly, this does not work for maps because `to` requires a type with one type argument (`ListBuffer[A]`, `Vector[A]`, etc), while all `Map` descendants have two (`HashMap[A, B]`, `TreeMap[A, B]`, etc).

In Scala 2.13 with its new collections library this could be written as follows:

```
val leavesValues = leaves.collect {
  case leaf: Leaf => leaf.value.toDouble
}.to(ListBuffer)
```

Note the round parentheses instead of brackets: in Scala 2.13, the `to` method accepts a reference to a companion object of a collection rather than collection type. In Scala 2.13, the collection library has different design; in particular, this new approach allows for map types as well:

```
val map: Map[Int, Int] = List(1 -> 2, 3 -> 4).to(Map)
```